# reading from coredata object

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am trying to fetch the values I have saved into my core data object, However I am getting this error

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'error'
```

This is pointing to the spot where I refrence **&error** in the below peace of code

```
// Test listing all FailedBankInfos from the store
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Manuf" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (Manuf *manuf in fetchedObjects) {

           // Log all of the values in the object  

        }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the error before you pass a reference to its location in the `executeFetchRequest`.

Like so:

```
NSError *error;
```